# Break down a total to multiple rows based on

Tags: sql, rows

I have one table with my invoice number and payment amount, for example:

```
invoice 1234   1000
```

I have another table with the jobs that amount is distributed to, for example:

```
Job 1   500   Invoice 1234
Job 2   200   Invoice 1234
Job 3   300   Invoice 1234
```

How do I get the 1000 to distribute out to the lines below properly.  There may be one line on the job distributions or more than what is shown above...just depends on the invoice.

Comment: Can you re-explain that last paragraph please.

Comment: please post some sample data, and your expected result.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It sounds like you are asking about how to allocate the 1000 to the second table, but that other table appears to already have those amounts. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your title ends at a very key moment: Break down a total to multiple rows based on ...?  Based on what?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me assume that you are using Oracle, since this is easiest in that database.

What you need is a cumulative sum, compared to the paid amount.  So, let me assume that you want to apply the payment to the earliest invoices.  The following query does this:

```
select i.*,
       (case when cumAmount <= p.payment then Amount
             when cumAmount - i.Amount < p.payment then p.payment - (i.cumAmount - i.Amount)
             else 0
        end) as AppliedPayment
from (select p.InvoiceId, sum(p.payment) as payment
      from Payment p
      group by p.InvoiceId
     ) join
     (select i.*,
             sum(i.amount) over (partition by i.InvoiceId order by i.JobNum) as cumAmount
      from Invoices i
     ) i
     on p.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
```

So, the idea is that you create a cumulative sum of the amounts from the invoices.  You then compare this to the payment.  When the cumulative sum is less than the payment, then you can apply the entire invoice amount.  When the cumulative sum is much greater than the payment, then nothing can be applied.  You have a boundary condition where you might have a partial payment.

The first subquery accumulates all payments for an invoice, to avoid duplicates.  The second subquery calculates the cumulative invoice amounts.

Some other databases support cumulative sum directly (SQL Server 2012).  In other cases, you need to do a self-join to get this result.